# mySQL do I need multiple Indexes to connect multiple tables with Foreign Keys to a single main table?

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I am building a record collection database.  I have a main Release table with Title, Artist, Format, Country, Date, Label, etc. - each of these will be a separate table with a Foreign Key connected back to Release.  My question is, do all of the foreign keys in their separate tables connect to one Primary Key (id) in Release or do they each connect to a corresponding Index integer key in Release?  And speaking of indexes - is it then necessary to create a separate index on all of the above which will be searched?

Thanks

Comment: you don't have ID column in the Release table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the info you have provided, you would have the following table structure

**Releases**

ID, Title, ArtistID,  FormatID,  CountryID,  Date,  LabelID

**Artists**
ID (foreign key to ArtistID in Releases table), Name, etc

**Formats**
ID (foreign key to FormatID in Releases table) , Name, etc

ect etc.

> is it then necessary to create a separate index on all of the above
>   which will be searched?

Depends on how you're planning to search the tables

EDITED:

> OK so each of the foreign keys in each table connects to its own id in
>   the Release table - not the primary id, correct?

Exactly. ArtistID will connect to the Artists table where ID is the primary key, but in the Releases table it is a foreign key. Same idea for the rest of the fields, except the Date.

> As for search it would be for example, search Artist (table will have
>   first name, last name or group name) which should connect to that
>   Artist's releases

Then you create an index on ArtistFirstName and ArtistLastName fields - these are the fields in the Artists table, and that is what your search is going to search. If you wish to display the artist's releases, then you have to join Artists and Releases tables on ArtistID (that you would get after search).

It would help if you read up more on the relational database design and normalization.

Comment: OK so each of the foreign keys in each table connects to its own id in the Release table - not the primary id, correct?  As for search it would be for example, search Artist (table will have first name, last name or group name) which should connect to that Artist's releases.  I don't think a first name Artist search is necessary, so should the Indexes be in the Artist table, and say, the Label table rather than the Release table?

Comment: OK thanks.  I think I'm doing this correctly.  This is only the start of a very large plan which I've posted here:      http://fanoss.ca/records-db.jpg

What is still missing is a "lookup table" for many-to-many relationships, but going through it I can see only a few of those -(vinylInnerSleeve, VinylInserts, CDInsert, TapeInserts, Relevance, Instruments, Vocals, Collaborator, and Role).  I'd just like to make sure that there isn't anything that won't work before I start putting it together.

Comment: that is a pretty large project for the first time design! I would recommend to design a sample of a smaller database so that you get the concept of relational databases first and then start adding more tables. Make sure that you don't normalize too much - pay close attention to the normalization chapter in your book/tutorial.